# neo4j - why and how create and use indexes?

Tags: neo4j

I'm learning Neo4J and it is working well without create any index.

I can create and read nodes fine.

So, why/when should I create indexes? Maybe for performance? Is it a must?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a lookup index when you are going to find nodes as *starting points*  by this properties, e.g. a `:Person(userId) or :Book(isbn) or :City(zip) or :Product(productNo)`.

Usually the stuff where you have a business (unique) identifier to find nodes.

In general for indexes there is some confusion because there are also legacy indexes (which are still used for fulltext and spatial) vs. the new exact schema indexes, see this post for more detail:

http://nigelsmall.com/neo4j/index-confusion